# What's wrong with this integration over the volume of a sphere (from Gauss' Theorem)?

Tags: integration, solution-verification, definite-integrals, fake-proofs, divergence-operator

I'm struggling to find my mistake in the following problem:

> Let $S$ be a sphere of radius $R$ with center at the origin.  Let $f(x,y,z) = 3z^2$.  Find the integral of $f$ over the volume of the sphere.
>
> [Source, p.3](https://www.lehman.edu/faculty/anchordoqui/VC-4.pdf)

My solution is below.  Where is my mistake?

---

The volume of the sphere can be parameterized using spherical coordinates $(\theta, \phi, r)$ with $$\theta \in [0, 2 \pi] \\ \phi \in [- \pi, \pi] \\ r \in [0, R] \\ z = r \sin \phi$$ giving $$\Phi = 3 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \int_0^R r^2 \sin^2 \phi \, dr \, d\phi \,d \theta.$$

Since the integrand is not a function of $\theta$, this simplifies to $$\begin{align}
\Phi &= 6 \pi \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \int_0^R r^2 \sin^2 \phi \, dr \, d\phi \\
&= 2 \pi \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}[ r^3 \Big|^{R}_0] \sin^2 \phi \, d\phi \\
&= 2 \pi^2 R^3.\end{align}$$

Yet the [source](https://www.lehman.edu/faculty/anchordoqui/VC-4.pdf) states the answer is $\frac {4 \pi R^5} 5$.  What is my mistake?

---

## Update

From the comments, it appears I'm missing something basic.  That is, this was not a careless mistake, but rather a gap in my understanding of how to do these types of integrals.

It seems I assumed the area of each small region is constant, namely $dr \, d\theta \, d \phi$.  But this is clearly not the case, since, for example, a constant change in $\theta$ will cover much more volume when $r$ is great than when its small.

This may be what Guliano meant by "you forgot the volume element in spherical coordinates" and Cunyi Nan meant by "You forgot to multiply the Jacobian".  I would request, if possible, elaboration.

Comment: To me it seems like you forgot the volume element in spherical coordinates.

Comment: The range of $\phi$ is $[0,\pi]$. You forgot to multiply the Jacobian.

Comment: And I checked the PDF file you linked, shouldn't the function $f(x,y,z)$ be $z^3$?

Comment: @CunyiNan 1. Can you elaborate on multiplying by the Jacobian? Or direct me to more information? 2. No, I believe it's $f(x,y,z) = \operatorname{div} z^3 k = 3z^2$.

Comment: Yes, go look at volume integrals in spherical coordinates in your text. $dV = r^2 \sin\phi dr\,d\phi\,d\theta$. Also, $z=r\cos\phi$ and $0\le\phi\le \pi$. Lots to get right. Check out my YouTube videos if your course hasn’t actually taught this.

Comment: To compute the integral $\iiint_{V}\mathrm{d}V$, use ball coordinates, I prefer to use $x=r\sin\phi\cos\theta,y=r\sin\phi\sin\theta,z=r\cos\phi$ where $0\leq\phi\leq\pi$ and $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$, the Jacobian of ball coordinates is $r^2\sin\phi$.

Comment: By the way, your text has the standard (non-American) switch of the letters $\phi$ and $\theta$.

Comment: @CunyiNan In English this is standardly called *spherical coordinates*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use spherical coordinates: $x=r\sin\phi\cos\theta,y=r\sin\phi\sin\theta,z=r\cos\phi$. Here $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi,0\leq\phi\leq\pi,0\leq r\leq R$.

The Jacobian of it is $\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(r,\theta,\phi)}=r^2\sin\phi$.

So the integral is
$$I=\iiint_{V}3z^2\mathrm{d}V=3\int_{0}^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta\int_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}\phi\int_{0}^{R}(r^2\sin\phi)\cdot(r^2\cos^2\phi)\mathrm{d}r=\frac{4\pi R^5}{5}$$